# These are drag and drop divs but i want to find x any y same value when resize the browser https://jsfiddle.net/tovic/mkUJf/

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

https://jsfiddle.net/TroyAlford/ZZEk8 i want this

```
$('.clickable').bind('click', function (ev) {
    var $div = $(ev.target);
    var $display = $div.find('.display');

    var offset = $div.offset();
    var x = ev.clientX - offset.left;
    var y = ev.clientY - offset.top;

    $display.text('x: ' + x + ', y: ' + y);
});
```

Comment: `.bind()` is depreciated. But you just use a `resize` Event.

Comment: @kamran can you tell me what error you get? Because i show jsfiddle its working

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/DGbT3/1/ this fiddle when i change the browser it will change the x,y position i want same value in all sizes browser

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/TroyAlford/ZZEk8/ i want this but its div not draggable.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/TroyAlford/ZZEk8/ if this div make draggable and gives same values of x and y in all sizes of browser my problems will be solve